# Can't get data from my table because of sql error java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt()?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I hope you're doing fine, I am having a little problem That I could not solve alone, I won't lie, I am a begginer when it comes to Spring and Java in general.

I am having this little bug as the title mentioned, I am trying to get data from a table called `tr_type_conformite`, so I created a Java DAO class to get the data from that table:

```
@Repository
public class ConformiteDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<Object, Long> implements ConformiteDao {

   @Autowired
   private ConfirmiteContratDaoJPA conformiteDaoJPA;

   @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
   @Override
   public CrudRepository getCrudRepositoryImpl() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public List<TrTypeConformite> recupererListeConformitePourContrat() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return getJPAQueryFactory().selectFrom(QTrTypeConformite.trTypeConformite).fetch();
   }

}
```

And here is my Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tr_type_conformite")
@Getter @Setter
public class TrTypeConformite extends AbstractTrEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, length=11)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private EnumTypeConformite type;

    @Column(name = "ordre", nullable = false, length=11)
    private int ordre;

}
```

And Here is my Enum :

```
public enum EnumTypeConformite {

    VIGIL("VIGIL"),
    PPE("PPE"),
    T("T");

    private String value;

    private EnumTypeConformite(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

But when I execute a service that call my DAO method, I get this big error :

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'T'

And of cource a big list of where my error came from, it is when I excute my service that call my DAO class.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the column definitions in the dbs?

Comment: Should'n't be: `private String ordre;` ?

Comment: @SteveSmith My Comlumns definitions ? meaning ?

Comment: What types are the columns, e.g. varchar, int, etc...

Comment: @juanlumn No I don't think so, I think it is because of My enumeration, but I don't know ho to solve the problem

Comment: @SteveSmith Well, code is a varchar and type is a varchar and ordre is an Integer.

Comment: I think you have to annotate the type column with @Enumerated, maybe `@Enumerated(EnumType.String)`.

Comment: @SteveSmith I will test it and see, Thanks Sir

Comment: @SteveSmith You re right, Can you write this an asnwer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: dmitrievanthony already has, so you might as well mark theirs as correct.  Thx.

Comment: you just were the first, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default JPA mapping of `enum` field is `int` column (see [EnumType.ORDINAL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html#ORDINAL)). If your column is string you need to use [EnumType.STRING](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html#STRING).

Try to annotate `enum` field like this:

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
private EnumTypeConformite type;
```